# Dropdown menus dependent on each other

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2012

I have three drop down menus that are using a store Procedure to populate my gridview. I need the first facility DropDown to give different options in the second source type dropdown depending on what facility is selected. Some facility's need to see all options and some only 1 or 2. I am unsure how to go about this.

Here is the code for the dropdowns and the store precedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    //set up arguments for the stored proc
    int? FacilityID = (ddlFacility.SelectedValue.Equals("-1")) ? (int?)null : int.Parse(ddlFacility.SelectedValue);
    int? SourceTypeID = int.Parse(ddlSource.SelectedValue);
    int? StatusTypeID = int.Parse(ddlStatusType.SelectedValue);
    //bind
    ObjectResult<models.MS_spGetMatchCross_Result> ds = this.DataLayer.model.MS_spGetMatchCross(FacilityID, SourceTypeID, StatusTypeID);
    gvResults.DataSource = ds;
    gvResults.DataBind();
}

private void ResetForm()
{
    try
    {

        //facility dropdown
        ddlFacility.Items.Clear();
        ddlFacility.DataSource = this.DataLayer.model.MS_spGetFacilityInfo(null).OrderBy(x => x.FacilityName);
        ddlFacility.DataTextField = "FacilityName";
        ddlFacility.DataValueField = "FacilityID";
        ddlFacility.DataBind();
        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a facility...", "-1"));

        //SourceType dropdown
        ddlSource.Items.Clear();
        ddlSource.DataSource = this.DataLayer.model.SourceTypes;
        ddlSource.DataTextField = "Description";
        ddlSource.DataValueField = "SourcetypeID";
        ddlSource.DataBind();

        //Match Status dropdown
        ddlStatusType.Items.Clear();
        ddlStatusType.DataSource = this.DataLayer.model.StatusTypes;
        ddlStatusType.DataTextField = "Description";
        ddlStatusType.DataValueField = "StatusTypeID";
        ddlStatusType.DataBind();

        BindGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.SetMessage(ex.ToString(), PageMessageType.Error);
        AISLogger.WriteException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag indicating what language this is...

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward, though not exactly elegant, way would be to handle the DropDownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged event.  For that to work, you'd have to make sure that each DDL whose selection will affect the contents of another DDL has the AutoPostBack property set to true (this ensures when something in the DDL changes, the page will cause a postback, allowing you to handle the change in server-side code).

In your first DropDownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler (in the code-behind), you'll have the following code:

```
// Handle selected item or selected index
if(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text=="Selection1")
{
   // Get items for DDL2
   var items=GetDataForDdl2();

   // Bind the data
   DDL2.DataSource=items;
   DDL2.DataBind();
}
```

You'd have similar logic for DDL2's SelectedIndexChanged event handler to then bind the items of DDL3, and so on.

For something that works nicely out of the box, check out the ASP.NET AJAX AjaxControlToolkit's CascadingDropDown: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Im a little confused about the "GetDataForDdl2" part. What should that be referencing. Do I just list what selections should go into the ddl2 after dd1 has been identified?

Comment: That's a placeholder method, since I don't know how you're retrieving the items for your DropDownList.  The idea is that within that method, you get the data out of a database, create it yourself, or retrieve it from something else.  The data would then be formatted in a List<T> or even a DataTable (though a DataTable is old and not the favored way of doing it anymore), so that the DDL can easily and natively databind to it.